# Dual stabilization doesnt work properly

Tags: duality, column-generation

I am currently trying to speed up my column generation approach to reduce the tailing-off effect. I have modified my master problem as follows. For this I have introduced $\phi_{ts}^+,\phi_{ts}^-,\chi_{ts}^+,\chi_{ts}^-,\varrho_{ts}^+\text{ and }\varrho_{ts}^-$. This results in the following master problem:

\begin{align}
\min \sum_{t\in T}^{}\sum_{k\in K}^{}slack_{tk}+\sum_{t\in T}^{}\sum_{k\in K}^{}\phi_{tk}^+\chi_{tk}^+ -\sum_{t\in T}^{}\sum_{k\in K}^{}\phi_{tk}^-\chi_{tk}^-
\end{align}

subject to:
\begin{align}
&\sum_{i\in I}^{}\sum_{r\in R_i} \lambda_{ir} motivation_{itk}^r+slack_{tk}+\chi_{ds}^+-\chi_{tk}^-\ge Demand_{tk}\quad &\forall t\in T, k\in K
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&\chi_{tk}^+\le \varrho_{tk}^+&\quad\forall t\in T,k\in K
\end{align}
\begin{align}
&\chi_{tk}^-\le \varrho_{tk}^-&\quad\forall t\in T,k\in K
\end{align}
\begin{align}
        &\sum_{r\in R_i}^{}\lambda _{ir}=1&\quad \forall i\in I
\end{align}

With $slack_{tk}, \chi_{tk}^+,\chi_{tk}^-\ge 0 t\in T, k\in K$ and $\lambda_{ir}\in \mathbb{Z}^+\forall i\in I, r\in R_i$.

As I understand stabilization, nothing should change in the optimal objective function value, only the number of iterations should possibly be reduced. However, when I implement and calculate it, the objective function value is lower than without stabilization, but $slack_{tk}$ is higher than in the initial model, since $\chi_{tk}^-$ takes values $\ge0$, while $\chi_{tk}^+$ in the final solution $=0\forall t \in T, k\in K$.

What could be the reason for this? Have I initialized the model incorrectly?

Comment: I suspect you want to have $+$ instead of $-$ before the last sum of the objective.

Comment: Well I adopted the methodology from here, and they do it the same way. https://doi.org/10.1016/S0012-365X(98)00213-1

Comment: Note that your original problem has $\ge$ constraints, whereas the original problem in the paper has equality constraints.